# How to design AsyncTask using Java Callable and Future?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, java.util.concurrent, callable

I am working on Java implementation of an Android class
[AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
I am using the Future and Callable classes of Java . Here is my Async Task :-

```
public abstract class AsyncTask<Params,Result>{

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    protected abstract Result runInBackground(Params params);
    protected abstract void postExecute(Result result);
    private Future<Result> future;

    public void execute(Params params) {
        future = executor.submit(new AsyncCallable<Params, Result>(params, this));
        try {
            postExecute(future.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

My AsyncCallable class which implements the Java Callable interface :-

```
public class AsyncCallable<Params,Result> implements Callable<Result>{

    private Params params;
    private AsyncTask<Params, Result> asyncTask;

    public AsyncCallable(Params params,AsyncTask<Params, Result> asyncTask) {
        this.params = params;
        this.asyncTask = asyncTask;
    }

    @Override
    public Result call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is executing");
        return asyncTask.runInBackground(params);
    }

}
```

And Here is my driver program which i am using to test the above program .

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        new AsyncTask<String, String>() {

            @Override
            protected String runInBackground(String params) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "Hello "+params;
            }

            @Override
            protected void postExecute(String result) {
                System.out.println(result+" AFter 10 sec");

            }

        }.execute("World");
        new AsyncTask<String, String>() {

            @Override
            protected String runInBackground(String params) {
                try {
                    //Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "Hello "+params;
            }

            @Override
            protected void postExecute(String result) {
                System.out.println(result+" AFter 2 sec");

            }

        }.execute("World");
    }
```

And here is the output which i am getting :-

```
pool-1-thread-1 is executing
Hello World AFter 10 sec
pool-2-thread-1 is executing
Hello World AFter 2 sec
```

If you see , my code is not running asynchronously , i.e both my AsyncTask are being implemented on the same thread . That is why it is waiting for the first Task to complete and after that my second AsyncTask is getting called .
Can you help me figure out the problem in my code

Comment: To elaborate on what Boris said: your code **is** working in a background thread (you have pool-1-thread-1 in the output). But each call to execute() calls future.get(), which is a blocking call, waiting for the task to complete.

Comment: Ok i get it that get() is a blocking call . But can you suggest any other method via which i can call my postExecute() method upon task completion .

Comment: Instead of calling postExecute(future.get()) inside my execute() method , i am calling postExecute() inside my call() method . Now it is working asynchronously

Comment: you can also check the source code of AsyncTask: 
https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java